# error junk after document element

Tags: xml, script, python-2.x

Tengo el un archivo xml con la siguiente estructura

```
<DATABASE><basedatos>control</basedatos><data>92.50</data><log>0.40</log></DATABASE><DATABASE><basedatos>db_medios</basedatos><data>22.50</data><log>0.40</log></DATABASE><DATABASE><basedatos>generales</basedatos><data>96.60</data><log>0.80</log></DATABASE>
```

y para el imprimir los datos tengo el siguiente script de phyton

```
from xml.dom import minidom

doc = minidom.parse("/var/www/zabbix/SE_SAPASE.xml")
data = doc.getElementsByTagName("data")[0]
print (int(float(data.firstChild.data)))
```

El problema es que a la hora de ejecutarlo me sale el siguiente error

> error junk after document element"

Se que se debe a que en el archivo xml hay más de un elemento root

como podría modificar el script par evitar este error

he echo lo que sugeriste "podrias crear una etiqueta raiz como ......" ahora lo que necesito es modificar el script para que me traiga el dato de cada base de datos por separado

```
<DATABASE><basedatos>control</basedatos><data>92.50</data><log>0.40</log></DATABASE><DATABASE><basedatos>db_medios</basedatos><data>22.50</data><log>0.40</log></DATABASE><DATABASE><basedatos>generales</basedatos><data>96.60</data><log>0.80</log></DATABASE>

control data 92.50
dbmedios data 22.50
generales data 96.60
```

Comment: podrias crear una etiqueta raiz como <root><DATABASE><basedatos>......</root>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En lugar de quedarte con el primer elemento `[0]` guarda todos los resultados de `doc.getElementsByTagName("data")` que serán una lista con todos los elementos `data` encontrados, e itera por ellos.

Usando `parentNode` puedes "subir" desde el nodo `<data>` al nodo `<DATABASE>` y desde este buscar `<basedatos>` para extraer el nombre. Así (suponiendo que tu XML tiene ya un nodo raiz englobando los tres nodos `<DATABASE>`):

```
data = doc.getElementsByTagName("data")
for elemento in data:
  nombre = elemento.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("basedatos")[0].firstChild.data
  valor = float(elemento.firstChild.data)
  print("{} data {}".format(nombre, valor))
```

Resultado:

```
control data 92.5
db_medios data 22.5
generales data 96.6
```

### Explicación

Cuando haces `data = doc.getElementsByTagName("data")` lo que obtienes en `data` es una lista, con tantos elementos como tags `<data>` hubiera en tu XML, en este caso tres.

Al hacer el bucle `for elemento in data`, cada iteración del bucle te devuelve uno de los elementos de la lista. Estos elementos son nodos XML y son un tipo especial de objeto implementado por la biblioteca `minidom`.

Esos objetos tienen campos como `firstChild`, que te devuelven su primer hijo, `parentNode` que te devuelven el nodo padre del elemento, y muchos más, pero en este caso no usamos el resto. Tendrías que mirar la documentación de `minidom`.

Si hacemos `elemento.firstChild`, ya que el elemento era el nodo `data` estaremos extrayendo el nodo de texto contenido en el tag `<data>`. Los nodos de texto tienen otro atributo llamado `.data` (es una desgraciada casualidad que se llame igual que el tag, no tiene nada qué ver) que nos permite acceder a la cadena en sí. Es por esto que `elemento.firstChild.data` nos daría la cadena `"92.50"` en la primera iteración del bucle, `"22.50"` en la segunda, etc.

Por otro lado si hacemos `elemento.parentNode` accedemos al "padre" de `<data>`, que es `<DATABASE>`. Sobre este nodo podemos hacer un `.getElementByTagName()` para buscar el tag `<basedatos>`, pues éste contiene el nombre de la base de datos. Como ya dijimos `.getElementByTagName()` devuelve una lista (con todos los tags encontrados), si bien en este caso sólo encontrará uno (recuerda que estamos buscando dentro de un `<DATABASE>`, no dentro del documento entero). Así que con `[0]` extraemos ese único elemento. Una vez extraído, usamos sobre él la técnica de `.firstChild.data` para obtener la cadena, que será entonces `"control"` en la primera iteración del bucle, `"db_medios"` en la segunda, etc.

De ese modo, en cada iteración del bucle puedo obtener el nombre de una base de datos y el dato correspondiente. Después los imprimo e itero para ir al siguiente elemento.

Comment: me podria inidicar en este caso elemento a que corresponde !!! que pena

Comment: No entiendo este comentario... ¿Quieres saber qué representa la variable `elemento`? Y qué es lo que es una pena?

Comment: si deseo saber a que equivale la variable elemento y la pena es por preguntate nuevamente

Comment: @danieltalero He ampliado la respuesta para añadir explicaciones. Espero te sirvan. No te lamentes por no entender, es normal al principio, y el parsing de XML no es tarea fácil